# Netlify CSS opacity loading bad ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs, netlify

Hello guys when i deploy my ReactJS app to Netlify my opacity of an element is set to 1% but on my local host it's set to 50%. Any suggestions at what is causing this problem?

[image: Netlify]

[image: My local host]

Comment: Did you try creating a build locally and deploy it ? Like is there a difference when you run your app as `npm start` vs when you run it like `npm build` or however you build it and then serve that build directory locally ?

Comment: I runned npm build and then i deployed that build to Netlify.  Everything is running OK just this opacity changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced 50% with 0.5 and now it is working.